# AngularJS - how to get coordinates of each item in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events

I have an items (div) in ng-repeat, each item has 200px height.
How i can get position relative to the window. If the distance to top window lower than 100px - i should hide this element.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle or plunker? anyway you can write own directive that can check distance and hide or show element

Comment: Here you are http://jsfiddle.net/ha3z9q4y/

Comment: but why you need hide manually? why not put repeated div in containter and set overflow:auto?

Comment: I need a similar kind of solution to this

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code I can't say how you to grab your element, but you will need to use `element.offsetTop` to get the distance from the top and `element.offsetLeft` to get the distance from the left.

You can then check this against your 100px limit.

Comment: yes, thank you, but i need to check position on realtime, for example, if user scrolling div with ng-repeat items ?